# BB 10 dev alpha simulator not loading

Tags: blackberry-simulator

I have installed Vmware player 4.0.4, BB10 dev alpha simulator in windows XP. While playing the virtual machine, it says [start service: screen] and after sometime gives error "Unable to open file for write. 2(No such file or directory)."

Please suggest a solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I just had boot load freezing at

> start service:screen.

Try not to change display settings of the virtual machine, Keep it as "use host settings for monitors".

Answer (score 0):

Just after your system starts it will get you briefly through a resolution list, unless you change it manually the system will continue booting 5 seconds later picking by default the first mode from the list,

to bypass this kind of error i chose one of the safe suggested modes on the bottom of the list, for example: in the following screenshot it will be 4,5 or 6

PS : don't forget to click somewhere inside the VMWarePlayer window to interact with the loaded system before typing the choice number with you keyboard then type enter (before the 5 seconds elapses)

[image]